# Is it possible to set a minimum Python version in Pygradle?

Tags: pygradle

[Pygradle](https://github.com/linkedin/pygradle) is used to build a python project.

**Problem**

The problem is that the CI runs a different Python version, resulting in different build outcomes, e.g. the build succeeded on the laptop, but failed on CI.

*CI*

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-2.9.1, py-1.4.29, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /home/travis/build/user/project, inifile: 
plugins: cov-2.2.1
collected 1 items
```

*Laptop*

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.5, pytest-2.9.1, py-1.4.29, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /home/user/dev/project, inifile: 
plugins: cov-2.2.1
collected 1 items
```

**Discussion**

To ensure that the build fails both locally on CI and on the laptop, the same python version should be used.

**Question**

Is it possible to set a minimum Python version in Pygradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Side note: personally I dislike using a *minimum* version: you never know beforehand how the language will evolve and if a certain future version will still be compatible with your code. For example many 2.7-compatible scripts can't actually work with python 3.X, setting 2.7 as the minimum version won't cut it.

I prefer to explicitly list as allowed the (existing) versions that I can test and confirm to be compatible. Any future version can be added later on, after such confirmation is obtained.

If you agree with the above then the [`com.linkedin.python`](https://github.com/linkedin/pygradle/blob/master/docs/plugins/python.md) plugin can apparently perform such version checks (it doesn't looks like it supports a *minimum* version):

> **Default and allowed Python version**
>
> This plugin enforces a set of default and allowed Python versions. For
>   example, you can specify `pythonVersion = '3'` and you will get
>   whatever the default Python 3 version is. Similarly `pythonVersion =
>   '2'` gets you whatever the default Python 2 version is.
>
> This plugin also enforces a set of allowed Python versions. If you
>   choose a Python version that is not allowed, you will see an error
>   messages such as:
>
> ```
> Python 3.2 not allowed; choose from [2.6, 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6]
> ```
>
> If you see this error message, you must adjust your `pythonVersion`
>   setting to one of the allowed values.
>
> Consumers of this extension can change the default Python 2, Python 3,
>   and allowed versions by making a call on the `PythonDetails` object,
>   either the one returned by `PythonExtension.getDetails()` or on any
>   `PythonDetails` instance you create, e.g. in Groovy:
>
> ```
> pythonDetails.setPythonDefaultVersions('2.7', '3.6', ['2.7', '3.5', '3.6'])
> ```

But I'm not familiar with pygradle, I can't really tell exactly how the plugin works and/or is configured to do the job.