# Is it possible to define a minimum code coverage using Pygradle?

Tags: pygradle

[Pygradle](https://github.com/linkedin/pygradle) is used to build and test a Python project. In gradle it is possible to define a minimum code [coverage percentage](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html):

> ```
> jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
>     violationRules {
>         rule {
>             limit {
>                 minimum = 0.5
>             }
>         }
>
>         rule {
>             enabled = false
>             element = 'CLASS'
>             includes = ['org.gradle.*']
>
>             limit {
>                 counter = 'LINE'
>                 value = 'TOTALCOUNT'
>                 maximum = 0.3
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

If this limit is not reached, build will fail. Is it possible to define a minimum code coverage using Pygradle?

When the above snippet is run, the build fails and the following is returned:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/user/SomeProject/build.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'SomeProject'.
> Could not find method jacocoTestCoverageVerification() for arguments [build_fsdafasdfsa] on root project 'SomeProject' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set a minimum Python version in Pygradle?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3150/is-it-possible-to-set-a-minimum-python-version-in-pygradle)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek This is not a duplicate of that Q&A as that one is about a minimum version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment it looks like it is not possible to define a minimum code coverage as the ticket that was created is still open https://github.com/linkedin/pygradle/issues/184